# TinyMce image plugin default dimensions

Tags: tinymce

We are using TinyMce with image plugin. https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/

This plugin by default adds image file dimensions, when width and height fields are left blank. Is there any way to prevent this using config? Or do I have to hack it?

Answer (score 7):

It's not exactly the logic you wanted, but it could be a good work-around.
You can change the size of the image when it is inserted into the textarea. The script sets the image width to a maximum of 1000px (you can adapt the algorithm to your needs)

```
selector: 'textarea',
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function(args) {
        editor = args.target;

        editor.on('NodeChange', function(e) {
        if (e && e.element.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
            width = e.element.width;
            height = e.element.height;
            if (width > 1000) {
                height = height / (width / 1000);
                width = 1000;
            }
        tinyMCE.DOM.setAttribs(e.element, {'width': width, 'height': height});
        }
        });
    });
}, ......
```

Comment: The first time I insert an image, I'm getting a width and height of 0. Weird. Seems to work ok after that...

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `image_dimensions` option to `false` the plugin no longer includes width and height when inserting an image:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/image/#image_dimensions

Comment: This one will remove input boxes for image dimensions completely. I want to keep these inputs, but prevent image plugin to set width and height automatically, when these inputs are left blank.

Comment: If you want to leave the options but only add the tag when you enter data into the dialog you will need to make a copy of the `image` plugin and modify it to meet that requirement - the plugin does not work that way as provided.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make your own version of the `image` plugin to do what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on robotu answer the react solution is like so, in my case I wanted a width of `100%` and a height of `370px` using `onNodeChange` function

```js
onNodeChange={(e) => {
  if (e && e.element.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
    editorRef.current.dom.setAttribs(e.element, {
      width: '100%',
      height: '370px',
    })
  }
}}
```

You can also customize the image width and height while editing

```js
init={{
  ...
  content_style:
    'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px } img { max-width: 100%; height: 370px; }',
}}
```

here is the full code to create your custom editor

```js
import { useRef } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react'

export default function MyEditor({
  initialValue,
  onChange,
  onFocus,
  ...props
}) {
  const editorRef = useRef(null)
  return (
    <Editor
      initialValue={initialValue}
      apiKey={process.env.REACT_APP_TINY_API_KEY}
      onInit={(evt, editor) => {
        editorRef.current = editor
      }}
      init={{
        placeholder: 'Insérer le contenu ici...',
        language: 'fr_FR',
        branding: false,
        // height: 500,
        menubar: true,
        plugins: [
          'template',
          'searchreplace',
          'quickbars',
          'image',
          'link',
          'codesample',
          'emoticons',
          'insertdatetime',
          'nonbreaking',
          'pagebreak',
          'advlist',
          'autolink',
          'lists',
          'link',
          'image',
          'charmap',
          'preview',
          'anchor',
          'searchreplace',
          'visualblocks',
          'code',
          'insertdatetime',
          'media',
          'table',
          'help',
          // 'wordcount',
        ],
        toolbar:
          'undo redo | blocks  | bold italic forecolor | link image| alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat searchreplace help',

        content_style:
          'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px } img { max-width: 100%; height: 370px; }',
        ...props,
      }}
      onEditorChange={onChange}
      onNodeChange={(e) => {
        if (e && e.element.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
          editorRef.current.dom..setAttribs(e.element, {
            width: '100%',
            height: '370px',
          })
        }
      }}
      onFocus={onFocus}
    />
  )
}

MyEditor.propTypes = {
  initialValue: PropTypes.string,
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  onFocus: PropTypes.func,
}
```